# Domain non-Administrator account with some elevated privileges

Tags: active-directory, windows-7

I'd like to create an account that is not a domain admin, so user cannot log into ADUaC, GP editor, etc but has privileges to access the Event Viewer, install printer drivers and applications on a client PC.

This will be for a student worker to help ease our workload and do basic troubleshooting. How can I create this type of ac

Comment: Every domain user can access ADUC, but not all can perform changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it seems that all the privileges are needed on the client side of things, so just add the student worker as a local administrator on all the machines that they'll need access to. Give them a normal domain user account and use Restricted Groups in group policy to add the user to the local Administrators group of the client machines.

Comment: We have hundreds of PCs across a campus environment, classrooms, faculty and staff machines. Adding users locally, and I'm assuming manually, is not feasible option.

Comment: @Sandy: Group Policies are created, applied, and administered  centrally, not at each client computer.  The client machines that are in the scope of the gpo download and apply the settings.

Comment: There's a feature called Restricted Groups that will allow you to modify the local Administrators group of all domain computers using Group Policy. You can use this feature to make the user a local Admin on as many machines as you need to.

Comment: It's worth adding that even the local Admin will have quite a bit of privileges, so a certain level of trust has to be placed with this Student Worker. This will provide you what you've requested, though.

Comment: We added a domain group to all out clients local admin groups using group policy.  We than add our desktop techs to this group and voila!

Comment: I would actually recommend uSlackr's method versus my suggestion because it's much more efficient to modify members of a group then it is to modify the Restricted Users policy and wait for it to redistribute to all the clients.

Answer (score 0):

Create a security account that gives access to local machines on the domain. Add the computers to this security account, and add the security account to the user. So... to further explain that;

You have computer A, B and C and user USER1.

Create a Security group called LOCALAD.

Add this security group to computers A, B and C and to USER1.

This will give them access to the computers, but not the servers.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like the a good fit for membership in the "Server Operators" and "Print Operators" domain groups.

Comment: I want this account not to have server privileges. I want them to have local administrator access on client PCs, and absolutely nothing on a server or domain settings.